# Getting AdView to work

Tags: java, android, libgdx, adview

I am developing a game in libgdx. I read the official docs and tried to integrate MobClix Ads in my App but eclipse can't resolve this constructor for ADView class: (for Example):

```
 AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d91b10f12454");
```

This line of code give me an error.

Maybe my import is not correct? I import this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

And the same for:

```
 adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I tried to search for an answer but I coudn't find, Does somone know how to resolve this?

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Please following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals.

Comment: I followed this one at [link](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx)

Comment: The link that you followed for admob library in that put in libs folder. Please follow my link so your problem with be resolved.

Comment: I need a link that explain how to do this in Libgdx not on a regular android application, I am not sure but I think it is not the same way.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code to mainactivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private StartAppAd add = new StartAppAd(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StartAppAd.init(this, "105158220", "205151606");
    //StartAppSearch.init(this, "105158220", "205151606");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(add.isReady())
    {
        add.showAd(); // show the ad
        add.loadAd();
    }   
        //a.loadAd(AdMode.FULLPAGE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    add.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    add.onBackPressed();
    super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    add.onPause();
    } 

}
```

put this into your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D
android:id="@+id/startApp3DBanner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**put this into ur Manifest file**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.start_up_app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="com.example.start_up_app.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:taskAffinity="com.example.start_up_app.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**for you have to use StartAppCommon-1.0.1.jar and StartAppInApp-2.0.7.jar**