# android: runtime Exception in android on admob banner

Tags: android, admob

Hi friends I am trying to create ad banner in android.
so I tried [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

but when I run My project is throws exception.
please help me out where i goes wrong.

**EXCEPTION**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.testapp/com.android.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

**Main Activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
            .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**manifest**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> 
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.testapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

please guied me weather i am on wrong track ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the library ??? Because the error said you are missing the Library? Have you placed the jar file in your libs Folder GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-x.x.x.jar

Comment: yes..i have downloaded & added in built path as well

Comment: clean your project and run. And is your adview present in the `activity_main` layout?

Comment: @user3110424 what do u mean by "And is your adview present in the activity_main layout?" I have posted code already.
& yes I have already posted jar file in libs forled as well

Comment: @PulahNandha Have you add the `AdActivity` in manifest.

Comment: Is the layout name in your case `activity_main` i have not seen what is your layout name. Can you post your manifest file code here ? Please have a look at here [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play)

Comment: I have added my menifest file.

Comment: Try the code on following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909448/getting-adview-to-work/22913475#22913475

Comment: Try the code from given link its working

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909448/getting-adview-to-work/22913475#22913475

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file add

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The above lines within `application` Tag.

For more detail refer to [Google Mobile Ads SDK Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.testapp/com.android.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

**I am getting this error. same as previous**

Comment: Have you gone through the link i have provided? Do you have the google play library in your workspace ?

Comment: yes..I have already downloaded it, its in `Reference Library` & copy & pasted in `libs` folder too

Answer (score 0):

In your tutorial you missed change in manifest

Add following

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"…/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: I have updated my menifest file. & one more thing is android:value have only 2 values true& false.(according to eclipes)