# com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, android, json, admob, adview

I am receiving  com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate  message on my main.xml when I clock show message I have following and its says source not found. Sorry I am not good developer, I just create my app by watched videos to learn. I am using android 4.4.2

```
Error
Fri Apr 18 13:11:54 BST 2014
com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:184)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:352)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:437)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:189)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:504)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:725)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1196)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.updateEditor(GraphicalEditorPart.java:953)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.onTargetLoaded(GraphicalEditorPart.java:917)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(AdtPlugin.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

my main.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_background"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#58ACFA"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bStart"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerValue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timerVal"
            android:textColor="#58ACFA"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDur"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView         
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="My ID" 
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and my **mainfest.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kolik.kolikbebek"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >


        <activity android:name=".Splash" > <!-- label comment at the beginandroid:label="@string/app_name"-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".AnneSesi" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.kolik.kolikbebek.ANNESESI" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SupurgeSesi" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.kolik.kolikbebek.SUPURGESESI" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.kolik.kolikbebek.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Menu" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.kolik.kolikbebek.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        </application>
</manifest>
```

My Java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button start, stop;
    private MediaPlayer mp;


    private TextView timerValue, display;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        display.setText("Kurutma");

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.elektirikli);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();

                //mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);


                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release(); // free up memory
                        mp = null;

                    }

                });

            }
        });

        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDur);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mp != null) {
                    try {

                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            // int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Post your java file code.

Comment: follow my link for full coding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909448/getting-adview-to-work/22913475#22913475

Comment: I added my java code GrlsHU.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have posted is an error from your Eclipse IDE. That is, it is a development time error not a runtime error.

This means that you have not correctly configured the path to your Android SDK in Eclipse.

Within Eclipse goto Window -> Preferences -> Android and browse to the SDK folder.

Comment: Thank you. How can I correct it,  I follow all steps by documents or videos? I set up all docs into one folder on desktop include my project too. what should I do? still receiving error? :(